# Узнать значение другого объекта с одинаковыми ключами

Tags: javascript

Есть объект A и B:

```
var A = {
    "test": "asd"
};
var B = {
    "test": {
        "asd": true
    }
};
```

Как узнать значение в B->test->asd по ключам из объекта A, что то вроде такого:

```
var x = B[A]; // нужно узнать какое значение хранит asd // true
console.log(x);
```

Есть ли простой способ? без циклов?

Comment: я в js не отец, но, как на счет: console.log(B.test.asd) ?

Comment: B.test[A.test] вернет true

Comment: Глубина ключей и имена ключей будет не известна...

Comment: Если глубина ключей и имена ключей заранее не известны, то без цилка и рекурсии не обойтись.

Comment: @bsbak приведите больше примеров с разными ключами/значениями и глубиной массива